# Problems inCharacter encoding

Tags: java, character-encoding

my code is: Default character encoding in ISO-8859-1

```
BufferedReader bis = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("somefile in unicode character"), "UTF-8"));
String str = bis.readLine();
bis.close();

PrintStream ps1 = new PrintStream(System.out, true, "UTF-8");
ps1.println(str);
```

The output should be the unicode characters 
of the file, but not getting.

Comment: Going to need sample input and sample output in addition to expected output.

Comment: Is your file *actually* in UTF-8, and do you know that your console supports using UTF-8? Where are you running this?

Comment: I am using some hindi characters, when i am directly pasting them on colsole it is printing correctly. i tried both netbeans and eclipse.

Comment: ya if i set encoding as UTF-8, things are fine, but why not it is reffering to the encoding i am specifying in the PrintStream constructor.

Comment: @RiteshKaushik: What OS? Works for me on Linux.

Comment: You still have not given any examples of what should be working, and what you are seeing instead.

Comment: @Mechanical snail : Windows XP

Comment: @RiteshKaushik, have you solved it? or what about the examples?

Comment: @emecas Yes, i solved it.The console always considers the default encoding.Since my output stream is `System.out` it will consider only default character encoding which is not `UTF-8` is my case.When i changed it to `UTF-8` it worked.